# How do I set a span element's HTML to the content of a custom data attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I'd like to show a count of the number of rows in a table. I've already calculated this with PHP and have outputted `<span>200 rows total</span>`, but I would like to use Javascript to toggle this to `<span>Showing 2 of 200 total rows</span>` if the table is collapsed. Ideally I'd like something like this:

```
$(".collapse-count").html('Showing 2 of ' + $(this).data("count") + ' total rows');
```

with markup:

```
<span class="collapse-count" data-count="200">Showing 2 of 200 total rows</span>
```

But this isn't working. How can I do this using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `this` in the proper context.

```
$(".collapse-count").html(function() {
    return 'Showing 2 of ' + $(this).data("count") + ' total rows');
});
```

---

When you pass a callback to `.html()`, the matched elements will be iterated, and `this` will be a reference to the current element in the iteration.

The way you had it, you were using whatever happened to be the enclosing value of `this`.

Answer (score 2):

`this` in your code doesn't refer to `.collapse-count` element, `html` method accepts a function, within the context of this function, `this` refers to the current element.

```
$(".collapse-count").html(function(index, oldHTML) {
   return 'Showing 2 of ' + $(this).data("count") + ' total rows';
});
```

Comment: That was quick. Thanks very much. :-)

Answer (score 2):

`this` doesn't have context of the element the way you are using it.

You can use the callback function argument of `html()` method:

```
$(".collapse-count").html(function(){
    return 'Showing 2 of ' + $(this).data("count") + ' total rows';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(".collapse-count").html(function() {
return 'Showing 2 of ' + $(this).attr("data-count") + ' total rows';
});
```

Comment: if more than one `'.collapse-count'` in page, will update all with attribute of the first one

Answer (score -2):

Working with `SPAN` you have to use `.text()` instead of `.html()`